# Please use substring matching on ignored and favorited tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I've ignored [windows-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone).  It should be possible to automatically determine that [windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8) is related, and ignore those too (specifically, my ignored tag is a subset of the other, counting only complete words).

In case I actually like a tag that is related to an ignored one, I could add it to favorites.  Like IP routing, longest match should take precedence.  For example, I do have [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) in my favorite list, but that's a shorter match when considering [windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8).

This will significantly reduce the maintenance necessary on ignored tag lists (why should my ignore list become ineffective just because Microsoft patches their handset OS?), while leaving the user in full control.

Please apply ignored and favorited tags using whole-word-substring matching.

If it's too expensive to do substring testing on every question, then suggesting similar tags when managing the ignored and favorited tag lists would be a good workaround.  (Without requiring me to retype the common portion 25 times... give me checkboxes for all the near matches, and preferably also for those similar to what I already have listed, not just what I'm typing)

Comment: Ignore `[windows-phone*]` instead...

Comment: @Ben: Can't, the UI requires picking an existing tag name.

Comment: You can; it's a implementation of what you asked for. Been around for years and I definitely use it.

Comment: I typed "windows-phone*" in the add ignored tag box and I get a dropdown of a zillion variations.  Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects the "best" match, removing the "*".  Oh, you have to visit the second-level tag management screen to do it.

Comment: Click the "Add" button instead. Eager autocompletion is messing you up. This is supported, Ben's exactly right. I use this constantly.

Comment: If you click the add button instead of pressing enter (some things already selected once the drop down appears) then it should work. I've just added it.

Comment: This needs to be more discoverable, and not blocked by the keyboard UI.

Comment: difficult to see this info amongst all the "wildcard searches" and ui concerns.. so +FFFF for `Click the "Add" button instead`! oh and where is the "second-level tag screen"?

Comment: @ocæon: I don't know if it exists anymore.  Five years ago, the main screen had a box for adding a favorite or ignored tag, but the list wasn't there.  You had to click a link to see and manage your list of favorited and ignored tags, and on that screen you could use the wildcard.  Now the wildcard can be entered from the home screen, but the keyboard UI still does its best to force you to pick from the picklist.  The escape key lets you dismiss the list without changing the wildcard you typed.